# How to compress Folder in nodeJS Mac without .DS_STORE

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, zip, nodejs-stream

Using the folder-zip-sync npm library and other zipping libraries, The .zip file gets saved with an extra .DS_STORE file. How to zip without this file? Is there a setting I can turn off? How to go about this?

```
var zipFolder = require("folder-zip-sync");
zipFolder(inputPath, pathToZip);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any library to compress
for this action use node js build in `zlib` module

```
const { createReadStream, createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const { createGzip } = require('zlib');
const inputFile = "./input.txt";
const outputFile = "./input.txt.gz";
const srcStream = createReadStream(inputFile)
const gzipStream = createGzip()
const destStream = createWriteStream(outputFile)

srcStream.pipe(gzipStream).pipe(destStream)
```